# dynamic html body script Var not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm working with amazon payments.

I'm dynamically inserting two scripts, one in head and one in body. But the SCRIPT element in my document BODY says the variable "OffAmazonPayments" in HEAD is not defined. The Variable in question is dynamically inserted into the HEAD of the document before the script in BODY, and is available from the console.

```
setupAmzn: () ->
    amazonLoginReady = document.createElement('script')
    amazonLoginReady.innerHTML = "
        window.onAmazonLoginReady = function() {
            amazon.Login.setClientId('CLIENT_ID_OBFU');
        }
    ";

    amazonWidgetJS = document.createElement('script');
    amazonWidgetJS.src = "https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/us/sandbox/js/Widgets.js";

    s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(amazonLoginReady, s)
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(amazonWidgetJS, s)

renderAmzn: () ->
    console.log("adding the login and pay button scripts")
    @setupAmzn()

    #create Login and Pay button

    payButtonContainer = document.createElement("div");
    payButtonContainer.setAttribute("class", "payButtonContainer");

    payButton = document.createElement("div");
    payButton.setAttribute("id", "AmazonPayButton"); 

    payButtonScript = document.createElement('script');
    payButtonScript.innerHTML = 'console.log(typeof OffAmazonPayments === "undefined")'; 

    # !!!!OffAmazonPayments is NOT in scope here 

    payButtonContainer.appendChild payButton
    payButtonContainer.appendChild payButtonScript

    proceed = @$('.proceed');
    proceed.append(payButtonContainer);
```

renderAmzn() is called in the render function of my Backbone.view. 
What am I doing wrong with the scoping of the variables? thank you.

Comment: Without code we cannot help you.

Comment: Where does `OffAmazonPayments` come from?

Comment: Sorry, this is CoffeeScript. I can only help with JavaScript.